# upload .pfx certificate through azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I want to upload .pfx certificate for my app service through azure devops task. can some one please help me on how to upload certificate through ARM Template

Answer (score 17):

You can follow below steps to upload certificate with ARM.

1,Go to the secure files under Pipelines, Library and upload your certificate. 
[image]

2, Add a [download secure file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) to download your certificate to your pipeline. you can reference to it by the path  `$(<mySecureFile>.secureFilePath) or $(Agent.TempDirectory)`. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information about predefined variables

3, add a powershell task to run below scripts to transform your certificate to base64 string. And store it to a self-defined environment variable `certificateBase64Content`. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) to learn more about variables

```
$secName = “<certificateName>.pfx
$tempDirectory = $env:AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY

$pfxFilePath = Join-Path $tempDirectory $secName

$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable

$cert.Import($pfxFilePath, "$(certificatePassword)", $flag)

$bin = $cert.RawData
$base64Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=certificateBase64Content;]$base64Value"
```

4,create a keyvault and grand the Microsoft.Web resource provider access to the KeyVault to get the certificate, which will be stored in the keyvault.

Please check blog ["Create the KeyVault with the required settings](https://blogs.4dotnet.nl/using-an-arm-template-to-deploy-your-ssl-certificate-stored-keyvault-on-an-web-app/)" part for ARM template example.

5, Store the certificate in the keyvault created in above step.

Please check blog **[Store the certificate in KeyVault](https://blogs.4dotnet.nl/using-an-arm-template-to-deploy-your-ssl-certificate-stored-keyvault-on-an-web-app/)** part for ARM template example.

6, Refer to the last step of the blog [Deploy the certificate to your Web App](https://blogs.4dotnet.nl/using-an-arm-template-to-deploy-your-ssl-certificate-stored-keyvault-on-an-web-app/) to deploy your certificate.

**Reminder**:

In above blog, the parameters defined in ARM template are override in the Azure resource group deployment task. You can configure this under the **Template** setting in the **azure resource group deployment task**
[image]

**Addition**:

If you donot want to use keyvault. You can omit above step 4,and 5.  And directly upload the cretificate after your cerficate being transformed and stored in the self-defined variable in above step 3. You need to replace `parameters('certificatePfxBase64')` with your self-defined variable `certificateBase64Content`

```
"variables": {
    "certificateName": "[concat(parameters('certificatePrefixName'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
"resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('certificateName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "pfxBlob": "[parameters('certificatePfxBase64')]",
        "password": "[parameters('certificatePfxPassword')]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "Certificate"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: can we upload certificate without using any key vaults

Comment: Yes, you can upload certificate without key vaults. Please refer to steps in this [blog](https://www.vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/deploying-a-web-certificate-with-arm-template-to-an-azure-resource-group-and-retrieving-certificate-thumbprint)

Comment: unable to open the link.. I need to install ssl certificate on App Service which is in App Service Environment...

Comment: You can ignore step 4 and 5 and  upload the base 64 string formated certificate. I updated above answer.

Comment: when i try to upload to App service environment, am getting access denied error while running through powershell script.. 
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName $webappname -ResourceGroupName $(RGName) -Name $fqdn `
-CertificateFilePath $pfxPath -CertificatePassword $pfxPassword -SslState SniEnabled

Comment: Can we install certificates through Powershell scripts with key vaults without ARM Templates..  I am using "New-AzWebAppSSLBinding" but getting not found error

Comment: You might need to get the certificate from key vault and then install it using New-AzWebAppSSLBinding. [Here](https://benohead.com/blog/2018/01/12/export-app-service-certificate-pfx-file-powershell/) is an example to export the certificate from keyvault using powershell.

Comment: In the above code i don't see anything that u r adding that certificate to any app service

Comment: I tried with the code u mentioned above with base64 ATM template code but getting error "Error occured when loading certificate from pfx file. Certificate blob cannot be decoded as a PFX packet."

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thnx.. Where would you @LeviLu-MSFT advise to store the `certificatePassword`? A property of the secure file or a variable group with passwords?

Comment: @GiedoDonkers You can define a pipeline [secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) to store the password.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT, I know I'm coming to this discussion late. However, I've got a question about the steps you've outlined in your answer. Do you put the downloading of the secure file in the Azure build pipeline, or in the Azure release pipeline?