# Need to upload private certificate to app service with custom domain through ARM tempalte

Tags: azure-devops

I need to install certificate to my app service with custom domain from ARM template without using any key vaults..

Comment: I am trying to upload with the below steps.
1. Using Download Secure file task
2. Converting the certificate to Base64 string.
3. Added Certificate and hostnameBindings resources in ARM Tempalte of Web App

Comment: am doing this without using any key vaults.. using ARM Template.. But am getting error while running the pipeline.

Certificate blob cannot be decoded as a PFX packet arm template

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [upload .pfx certificate through azure devops pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085396/upload-pfx-certificate-through-azure-devops-pipeline)