# Modern Approach to WPF Telerik Grid Manifest Azure DevOps

Tags: wpf, azure-devops, manifest, credentials, telerik-grid

Is there a modern approach to exclude manifest certificate private keys from a repository deployment using Azure DevOps without losing related functionality?

I am migrating a code repository that contains a WPF Telerik grid from Team Foundation Server to Azure DevOps. I noticed sensitive information such as an X.509 Certificate Private Key in a TemporaryKey.pfx file that seems to handle the Telerik grid manifest download in production.

I attempted to removed the manifests and OneClick signing outright and see related pages are now throwing errors like the following:

> Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash
> Within the .csproj

I see 2 potential lines to remove from the .csproj but I do not want to introduce a security risk if this is a critical security component.

```
<GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
<SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
```

Using a key vault would be another alternative, however I imagine this is circumventing a larger security issue.

Edit:
After some trial and error I have included the corresponding pfx as a secure file and added powershell scripts to install the pfx on the local agent and sign the manifest as I would in the regular application (Sign the OneClick manifests). Now I am receiving

> Error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: A certificate chain
> could not be built to a trusted root authority.

My YAML looks like the following:

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
        name: TemporaryKey
        displayName: 'Download TemporaryKey certificate'
        inputs:
          secureFile: 'TemporaryKey.pfx'

      #Install TemporaryKey certificate for manifest
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Write-Host "Start adding the PFX file to the certificate store."
            $secName = "TemporaryKey.pfx"
            $tempDirectory = $env:AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY

            $pfxFilePath = Join-Path $tempDirectory $secName

            Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
            $cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
            $cert.Import($pfxFilePath, "$(Password)", [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
            $store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
            $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
            $store.Add($cert)
            $store.Close()
      
      
      #Sign manifest using TemporaryKey
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: "Sign TemporaryKey PowerShell script"
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $magicToken = "#PerformScriptSigning"
            $encoding = "UTF8"
            $scriptFolder = "."
            #No files found here
            $scripts = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptFolder -Filter "*.ps1" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
            foreach ($script in $scripts) {
                try {

                    $content = Get-Content -Path $script.FullName -Encoding $encoding
                    if ($content.Contains($magicToken)) {
                        $content = $content | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $magicToken}
                        Set-Content -Value $content -Path $script.FullName -Encoding $encoding -Force
                        # load cert
                        $codeSigningCert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My -CodeSigningCert | Select-Object -First 1
                        Write-Output "Signing script `"$($script.Name)`" with certificate `"$($codeSigningCert.Thumbprint)`""
                        # sign script
                        $null = Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $codeSigningCert -FilePath $script.FullName -TimestampServer "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161"
                        # copy to artifact staging location
                        $null = Copy-Item -Path $script.FullName -Destination $env:Build_ArtifactStagingDirectory
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Error $_
                }
            }
```

From my understanding this process should create .ps1 files to sign the project, however there are no .ps1 files found in the signing script. The install script can open the file and does successfully install it to the store. I wrote out the TemporaryKey.pfx cert from before storing it to ensure it was opening without error.

I'm not clear how signing works in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The "modern" or recommended approach would be to upload the `.pfx` file as [secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) to Azure DevOps and then download it and sign your app with it during the build or release pipeline.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/june/devops-msix-the-modern-way-to-deploy-desktop-apps-on-windows) contains an example of a YAML pipeline that uses a secure `.pfx` to sign an MSIX packaged WPF app.

Comment: Thanks for articles, based on what you provided I see a solution that implements it nicely here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085396/upload-pfx-certificate-through-azure-devops-pipeline.

Comment: Hi @Alex, Would you mind sharing your answer here and accepting it? It could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT, I definitely will. I have secured my .pfx file and downloaded it in the build pipeline. I still need to store it in a variable and deploy it. Once these are complete, I will reply with the steps I took.

Comment: I have confirmed the pfx is installed on the agent before the build and should be working. I am getting error "Error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority." If I can resolve this and confirm a successful build. I will answer this question with a combination of sources I found helpful.

Comment: Hi @Alex, Could you edit your issue description and share the latest issue here? Thanks

Comment: @Vito Liu-MSFT, please see the latest edit on the question.