# Azure build pipeline: Is it possible to sign an MSIX within the VSBuild task using a code signing certificate stored in the Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, code-signing, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am able to sign an MSIX file within the VSBuild task when using a code signing certificate (*.PFX) that is stored as a secure file from the Build Pipeline's library section using the following setup (truncated for brevity):

Note: The key is how we are assigning the `p:PackageCertificateKeyFile` argument.

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Dev (SomeGuid)'
    KeyVaultName: 'SomeKeyVault'
    SecretsFilter: 'SomeCertPassword'
    RunAsPreJob: false
    
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: signingCert
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'SomeCertName.pfx'  
    
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    solution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '
      /p:AppInstallerUri=$(msixInstallUrl)
      /p:AppxBundle=Never 
      /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" 
      /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/" 
      /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true
      /p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=true      
      /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="" 
      /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile="$(signingCert.secureFilePath)"
      /p:PackageCertificatePassword="$(SomeCertPassword)"
      /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideLoadOnly 
      '
```

However, as an alternative to storing the code signing certificate within the secure files section of the pipeline library, I would like to store it in the Key Vault's certificate section and then just retrieve that within the `AzureKeyVault` task. So, the YAML would look something like this (truncated for brevity):

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Dev (SomeGuid)'
    KeyVaultName: 'SomeKeyVault'
    SecretsFilter: 'SomeCertName,SomeCertPassword'
    RunAsPreJob: false
        
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    solution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '
      /p:AppInstallerUri=$(msixInstallUrl)
      /p:AppxBundle=Never 
      /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" 
      /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/" 
      /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true
      /p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=true      
      /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="" 
      /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile="$(SomeCertName)"
      /p:PackageCertificatePassword="$(SomeCertPassword)"
      /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideLoadOnly 
      '
```

The reason for wanting to do it this way is because I get `cannot find *.appinstaller` file when I try to run a separate `MSIX Code Signing` task. It just seems simpler and easier to sign the package within the same build task.

But, I get the following error:

> Error APPX0104: Certificate file '***' not found. C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual

From what I can tell, when the certificate file is retrieved from the `AzureKeyVault` task variable, it is stored as a string as opposed to a file. But, the MSBuild task is expecting a file. I have tried searching all over the web and tried some Powershell scripts to convert the imported `AzureKeyVault` task variable from string to base64, but I am having no luck (see links below for reference). I have literally tried about 40 different ways of doing this and I'm afraid that an attempt to list them would only confuse the question. As a result, I felt it better to present what I am trying to do and ask if it is even possible, and if yes, how?

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kv/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59098706/4630376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by installing the *MSIX Packaging* extension to my Azure subscription, as referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/msix-packaging-extension?tabs=yaml

This extension is extremely useful because, much like the *Azure Sign Tool (AST)*, which seems to be the only alternative to this method, it handles the converting of the code signing certificate `string` to `base64` and then signing the package. Obviously, there is a lot going on under the hood. You will need to configure your build pipeline to have access to the key vault. However, unlike the *AST*, this extension is far easier to use because it does not require all of the configurations that the *AST* requires. This is because the *AST* handles the task of retrieving the code signing certificate from the key vault whereas in my implementation I just use the *Azure Key Vault* task to pull the file into my build pipeline, which is also fairly easy to setup and implement. From my perspective, *AST* is too complicated to be useful.

Below is the full implementation that I use, which also parameterizes the Key Vaults that store the various code signing certificates by our subscriptions/environments.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/main
    - refs/heads/demo
    - refs/heads/develop
# The following is for testing purposes only. For now we disable automatically building for commits to feature branches in develop.
#    - refs/heads/feature*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

# Variable Declaration(s)
# Note: We must use the name/value combination because we are (dynamically) mixing in variable groups.
variables:
- name: buildPlatform
  value: 'x64'
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: 'Release'
- name: major
  value: 1
- name: minor
  value: 0
- name: build
  value: 0
- name: revision
  value: $[counter('rev', 0)]
# Set conditional variable group based off of the trigger branch (see trigger section above).
# Note: If we use SourceBranch then it will append `refs/heads/` to the SourceBranchName.
- ${{ if eq(variables['build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
  - group: PROD
- ${{ if eq(variables['build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/qa') }}:
  - group: QA
- ${{ if eq(variables['build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop') }}:
  - group: DEV
# The following is for testing purposes only.
# Note: If you want to run for a feature branch in develop then you must uncomment this line. Otherwise, you will get an error that the pipeline is not valid.
#       "Step AzureKeyVault input ConnectedServiceName references service connection $(azureSubscription) which could not be found."
- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature') }}:
  - group: DEV

steps: 
# Update the AppXManifest file's major, minor, build, and revision parameters with the current values.
# Note: We use the day's build counter to determine the revision number.
#       By rule, this counter is limited to 255 values per day and will start over at 1!
- powershell: |
   [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Xml.Linq")
   $path = "SomeAppName.MsixInstaller/Package.appxmanifest";
   $doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($path);
   $xName = [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Identity");
   $doc.Root.Element($xName).Attribute("Version").Value = "$(major).$(minor).$(build).$(revision)";
   $doc.Save($path);
  displayName: 'Version the Package Manifest'
  
# Retrieve the code signing certificate from the Key Vault.
# Note: 20211008 - Ignore the errors because the values are correct.
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: Retrieve Variable(s)'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
    KeyVaultName: '$(keyVaultName)'
    SecretsFilter: 'SomeCertName'
    RunAsPreJob: false

# Specify the minimum version of NuGet that we want to use to restore the solution's NuGet packages.
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'NuGet: Use v5.11.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.11.0
    checkLatest: true

# Run NuGet restore to download the NuGet packages before building the solution.
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet: Run restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

# Build the MSIX package.
# Note: Set AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false to avoid a build error (i.e., missing thumbprint). We will sign the package in a subsequent step.
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'VSBuild: Build the MSIX package'
  inputs:
    clean: true
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    restoreNugetPackages: false  #adding this because we're doing an explicit restore above, lets skip the implicit restore.
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '
      /p:AppInstallerUri="$(appServiceUri)"
      /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/" 
      /p:AppxBundle=Never 
      /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" 
      /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideLoadOnly 
      /p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=true
      /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false
      '

# Sign the MSIX package with the code signing certificate from the Key Vault.
- task: MsixSigning@1
  displayName: 'Code Sign MSIX Package'
  inputs:
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\**\*.msix'
    certificateType: 'base64'
    encodedCertificate: '$(DeveloperCodeSigningCertFile)'
    continueOnError: true

# Publish the MSIX package in preparation for deployment. This will be consumed by the Release Pipeline.
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish ArtifactName: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
    
# Run tests (if any).
# Note: This tests sources that are found matching the given filter '**\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VSTest: Run Tests (if any)'
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```